DearPyGui window contents scale down after calling any matplotlib function
I have a DearPyGui button that opens a matplotlib graph, although after running any plotting commands the whole DearPyGui viewport shrinks by about 50%.
Here's some example code that demonstrates this behaviour:
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def open_graph():
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    plt.show()

dpg.create_context()
dpg.create_viewport()
dpg.setup_dearpygui()

with dpg.window(label="Example Window", tag="primary"):
    dpg.add_button(label="Open Graph", callback=open_graph)

dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.set_primary_window("primary", True)
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()

I've already tried changing the matplotlib backend (although I haven't tried all of them) and even running matplotlib on a different thread but that hasn't had any effect.
